# Unable to install Homebrew + fish terminal (Mac)

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

I am unable to install Homebrew(http://brew.sh/) using the fish command shell (http://fishshell.com/) on my Mac. Here is the error I get:

```
$(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(curl)'.

fish: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Please suggest!

Comment: You might want to read about [alternative installation methods](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start bash and execute the unmodified command line.

Bash supports the syntax `$(command)` to return the text result of a command. Fish doesn't, but instead uses `(command)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The command doesn't seem to work on fish without the leading $. MacBook-Pro ~> ruby -e "(curl -fsSL raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"; -e:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (curl -fsSL raw.githubusercontent.com/H... ^ –

Comment: Was wondering if there is a way to do it from fish. Thanks anyway

Comment: The bash and fish languages have significant differences. In general, you wouldn't try to run a Python script through the Ruby interpreter, and for basically the same reason, and even if you like fish better overall, you should probably stick to bash when bash is expected.

Answer (score 4):

In Fish, command substitutions are just in parentheses, without the leading `$`. This should work:

```
ruby -e "(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Or you can just run that command from bash:

```
bash
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
exit
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The command doesn't seem to work on fish without the leading $. 
MacBook-Pro ~> ruby -e "(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/H...
                  ^

Comment: Try removing the double quotes.

Comment: Your first suggested command doesn't work with fish.  I get an error `syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/H...`